# Using Cocos2d to create a CCMenuSprite shows image incorrectly

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game with Cocos2d for the iPad.  I have created an Image that I would like to use for my menu, as the regular ItemLabel is flat and ugly.  The following shows the same image, but the one on the top is the MenuItem using this code:

```
CCMenuItemImage *itemEasyLevelImage = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"Old_Slow_Menu.png" selectedImage:@"Old_Slow_Menu.png" block:^(id sender){...
```

The bottom image is the same using this code:

```
CCSprite *oldSlow = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Old_Slow_Menu.png"];
oldSlow.position = ccp(size.width /2, size.height /2);
[self addChild:oldSlow z: 10];
```

Any ideas why the image shows up all messed up, as shown in this image:

[image]

Comment: My guess is that something not shown in your code here is changing the color property of the menu item to `ccc3( 255, 0, 0 )`.

Comment: Thank you.  You hit the nail on the head.  Since I was using labels and trying to switch to images, I was changing the menu.color = CCRed.  I took that out, and Viola... it worked.. Awesome!!!!

Comment: cool. I added it as an answer in case you want to accept one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that something not shown in your code here is changing the color property of the menu item to ccc3( 255, 0, 0 ).